# Return value from writing an unused parameter when falling off the end of a non-void function

Tags: c, gcc, x86, return-value, kernighan-and-ritchie

In this [golfing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/189517/17360) I saw a trick where the return value is the second parameter which is not passed in.

```
int f(i, j) 
{
    j = i;   
}

int main() 
{
    return f(3);
}
```

From [gcc's assembly output](https://godbolt.org/z/yHKS37) it looks like when the code copies `j = i` it stores the result in `eax` which happens to be the return value.

```
f:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
        movl    %esi, -8(%rbp)
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $3, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    f
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

So, did this happen just by being lucky? Is this documented by gcc? It only works with `-O0`, but it works with a bunch of values of `i` I tried, `-m32`, and a bunch of different versions of GCC.

Comment: The code in the page you link to has `i=j;`. The code in this question has `j = i;`, which is swapped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**gcc `-O0` likes to evaluate expressions in the return-value register, *if* a register is needed at all.**  (GCC `-O0` generally just likes to have values in the retval register, but this goes beyond picking that as the first temporary.)

I've tested a bit, and it really looks like GCC `-O0` does this on purpose across multiple ISAs, sometimes even using an extra `mov` instruction or equivalent.  IIRC I made an expression more complicated so the result of evaluation ended up in another register, but it still copied it back to the retval register.

Things like `x++` that can (on x86) compile to a memory-destination inc or add won't leave the value in a register, but assignments typically will.  So it's note quite like GCC is treating function bodies like [GNU C statement-expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

---

This is *not* documented, guaranteed, or standardized by anything.  It's an implementation detail, not something intended for you to take advantage of like this.

**"Returning" a value this way means you're programming in "GCC -O0", not C.**  The wording of the code-golf rules says that programs have to work on at least one implementation.  But my reading of that is that they should work *for the right reasons*, not because of some side-effect implementation detail.  They break on clang not because clang doesn't support some language feature, just because they're not even written in C.

Breaking with optimization enabled is also not cool; some level of UB is generally acceptable in code golf, like integer wraparound or pointer-casting type punning being things that one might reasonably wish were well-defined.  But this is pure abuse of an implementation detail of one compiler, not a language feature.

I argued this point in comments under [the relevant answer on Codegolf.SE C golfing tips Q&A](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2203/tips-for-golfing-in-c/106067#106067) (Which incorrectly claims it works beyond GCC).  That answer has 4 downvotes (and deserves more IMO), but 16 upvotes.  So some members of the community disagree that this is terrible and silly.

---

Fun fact: in ISO C++ (but not C), having execution fall off the end of a non-`void` function is Undefined Behaviour, *even if the caller* doesn't *use the result*.  This is true even in GNU C++; outside of `-O0` GCC and clang will sometimes emit code like `ud2` (illegal instruction) for a path of execution that reaches the end of a function without a `return`.  So GCC doesn't in general define the behaviour here (which implementations are allowed to do for things that ISO C and C++ leaves undefined.  e.g. `gcc -fwrapv` defines signed overflow as 2's complement wraparound.)

But **in ISO C, it's legal to fall off the end of a non-void function: it only becomes UB if the caller uses the return value**.  Without `-Wall` GCC may not even warn.  [Checking return value of a function without return statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638963/checking-return-value-of-a-function-without-return-statement)

With optimization disabled, function inlining won't happen so the UB isn't really compile-time visible.  (Unless you use `__attribute__((always_inline))`).

---

**Passing a 2nd arg merely gives you *something* to assign to.  It's not important that it's a function arg**.  But `i=i;` optimizes away even with `-O0` so you do need a separate variable.  Also just `i;` optimizes away.

Fun fact: a recursive `f(i){ f(i); }` function body does bounce `i` through EAX before copying it to the first arg-passing register.  So GCC just really loves EAX.

```
        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
        movl    %eax, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax             # without a full prototype, pass # of FP args in AL
        call    f
```

`i++;` doesn't load into EAX; it just uses a memory-destination `add` without loading into a register.  Worth trying with gcc -O0 for ARM.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/e54qnKr7q - example of C vs. C++ fall-off-end of non-void function behaviour difference in GCC's warning and code-gen.