# Why GCC loads integer first to eax and then to some other relevant registers?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86

Using [this](https://godbolt.org/z/qGqE9b) site, I generated assembly code for a simple program.

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 5
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        mov     edi, eax
        mov     eax, 0
        call    ifunc
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

Here value of a is loaded from memory into eax and then it is moved to edi to pass to function. But I wrote a similar assembly code and directly loaded value of a into edi. Both works fine. Does GCC follows this for some kind of optimization? What is the benefit of loading eax first?

Comment: Add `-O3` to the compiler options to see the optimized code. https://godbolt.org/z/WMEd4Y

Comment: So, this is just unoptimized code and has nothing to do with some special behavior of either eax or edi?

Comment: You could consult your assembler manual to see what instructions and addressing modes are valid....

Comment: @EugeneSh. Also add `extern void ifunc(int);` above main to get rid of that mysterious extra `xor eax, eax` before the call.  (Without a prototype, `ifunc` is treated as variadic.)

Comment: @zwol Yep. Also have to explicitly mention `void` argument if function accepts no argument.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB Yes, in C `T fn()` isn't a prototype.

Comment: Near duplicate of [Return value in unused parameter when falling off the end of a non-void function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57437831) - GCC `-O0` evaluates expressions in the return-value register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does GCC follows this for some kind of optimization?

Just the opposite.  You're compiling *without* optimizations so gcc *doesn't* do the optimization that would have removed the redundant `mov`s and the unnecessary allocation of `a` as a variable in stack memory.

> What is the benefit of loading eax first?

It has none and is just redundant.  It is very common for unoptimized compiler code to contain stupid-looking stuff like this.

Comment: GCC `-O0` likes to evaluate non-constant expressions in the return-value register (if it needs a register at all), even across other ISAs.  It's common these days for CodeGolf.SE C answers to depend on that behaviour ([Tips for golfing in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106067)), which means they're actually written in `gcc -O0` language, not even trying to really be C, unfortunately.  I mention this only because it's led to some more detailed discussion of the fact that GCC uses EAX this way.

Comment: Related: [Return value from writing an unused parameter when falling off the end of a non-void function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57437831) - further discussion of GCC evaluating expressions into the return-value register, on any ISA I've looked at.  (But mostly just pointing out that falling off the end of a non-`void` function after doing this only "works" because of that coincidence.)