# copying string in c in a microcontroller

Tags: c

I have a string `"Revision: BG96MAR02A07M1G"` which is stored in char tempdata[512]

I'm trying to parse and copy only that part **BG96MAR02A07M1G**

this what I did, but I get garbage values in firmwareVersion

```
signed char updateBG96FirmwareVersion(int timeout)
{
    char firmwareVersion[24];
    char *ret = NULL;

if (GSMCommand("I", tempdata, timeout) != AT_OK)
        return FEHLER;

    ret = strstr(tempdata, "Revision:");
    if (ret)
    {
        strncpy(firmwareVersion, tempdata+9, 24);
        firmwareVersion[sizeof(firmwareVersion)] = '\0';
    }
    else
        return FEHLER;
}
```

[test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghN1c.png)

Comment: Beware of `strncpy`. It is not at all the somewhat safer verion of `strcpy`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm using it in an embedded software, the compiler Keil doesn't follow latest standards

Comment: `firmwareVersion[sizeof(firmwareVersion)] = '\0';` breaks the array bounds.

Comment: You need to terminate the *actual* length of the substring, not the array size. `BG96MAR02A07M1G` is only 15 characters.

Comment: @WeatherVane Can you write an answer to clarify it ?

Comment: @WeatherVane ```strncpy(firmwareVersion, tempdata+10, 25);
  firmwareVersion[15] = '\0';``` doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
#include <string.h>

#define FEHLER 123   // ?
#define SUCCESS 0

signed char updateBG96FirmwareVersion(int timeout)
{
  char firmwareVersion[24];
  char* ret = NULL;

#if 1
  char tempdata[] = "Revision: BG96MAR02A07M1G";  // Test data for my test
#else
  if (GSMCommand("I", tempdata, timeout) != AT_OK)
    return FEHLER;
#endif

  const char revision[] = "Revision: ";
  ret = strstr(tempdata, revision);
  if (ret)
  {
    strcpy(firmwareVersion, tempdata + strlen(revision));
    return SUCCESS;
  }
  else
    return FEHLER;
}

int main() // main function initializing here 
{
  updateBG96FirmwareVersion(0);
}
```

This assumes that the revision string `BG96MAR02A07M1G` is never longer than 24 characters. Otherways you probably should use `strncpy` and terminate the string with a 0 manually.

Comment: BTW:  `updateBG96FirmwareVersion` doesn't return anything in case of success. I edited the answer slightly

Comment: that's weird, without     return SUCCESS;
it corrupts the data

Comment: Maybe the code that calls `updateBG96FirmwareVersion` does something weird if un unexpected value is returned. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638963/checking-return-value-of-a-function-without-return-statement

Comment: @andreahmed the version without the `return SUCCESS` should compile with a warning: https://www.godbolt.org/z/3WhTYP8av